# C - Printing Bin. File In Weird Symbols

Tags: c

I created a function that is successfully reading the binary file but it is not printing as I wanted.

**The function:**

```
void print_register() {

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("data.bin", "rb");

    if (fp == NULL) {
        error_message("Fail to open data.bin for reading");
        exit(0);
    }

    reg buffer;

    while (EOF != feof(fp)) {
        fread(&buffer, sizeof(reg), 1, fp);
        printf("%s %d %d\n", buffer.name, buffer.age, buffer.id);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Note: `reg` is a `typedef` for a `struct`:

```
typedef struct registers reg;
struct registers {
    char name[30];
    int age;
    int id;
    char end;
};
```

**Function for writing the file:**

```
void register_new() {

    system("clear");

    reg buffer;

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("data.bin", "ab");

    if (fp == NULL) {
        error_message("Error opening file data.bin");
        exit(0);
    }

    write_register(buffer);

    fwrite(&buffer, sizeof(reg), 1, fp);

    fclose(fp);
}
```

**Posting a printscreen of what was print to be more helpful:**

[image: Console Image]

As you can see on image, after the "p" (command for printing) is where should be the name, age and id of the struct.

Comment: I think that you need to post your code for the Save command too, seems like a problem there.

Comment: Where is the declaration of `reg`? Also, `while (!feof(fp)){` is [wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).

Comment: What is `reg`? It better have enough storage space for your string. What is in that file? It does not appear to contain text. Perhaps - if you created it as well - you stored a *pointer* to your text, instead of the actual text.

Comment: Maybe it's not the printing part that's broken but `write_register()`. Did you make sure `data.bin` contains valid data? (you could use `hexdump` or similar tools to check your file's content).

Comment: @Mike did some edits, maybe it helps

Comment: You are open a file a binary: `fp = fopen("data.bin", "rb");`. Consider open it as text file: `fp = fopen("data.bin", "rt");`. You are using `printf("%s ... , `buffer.name`. You must make sure the C string buffer.name is NULL terminated (ends with zero).

Comment: @RadLexus did put a note to say that, but did edit with the code for it

Comment: @Rotem the "rt" mode didn't work, also used scanf for inserting names so everything is null terminated.

Comment: You can't just use "rt", you need to modify all reading and writing operations to text operations. You can work with binary as well...

Comment: "successfully reading the binary file" and `while (EOF != feof(fp)) {
        fread(&buffer, sizeof(reg), 1, fp);
        printf("%s %d %d\n", buffer.name, buffer.age, buffer.id);
    }` do not agree.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39058843/2410359).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `register_new()`, you have to send **the address** of `buffer` in order for `write_register()` to work properly (right now you're giving it a copy of buffer).

Replace:
`write_register(buffer);`
with:
`write_register(&buffer);`

Then correct `write_register` to take and work with an address instead of a structure.

This might help you understand what's going on: [http://fresh2refresh.com/c-programming/c-passing-struct-to-function](http://fresh2refresh.com/c-programming/c-passing-struct-to-function/)

Answer (score 3):

Your reading loop is incorrect. Don't use `feof()`, it can only tell is you have reached the end of file after a read attempt failed and it might not return `EOF` anyway, it is only specified as returning 0 or non 0.  Use this instead:

```
while (fread(&buffer, sizeof(reg), 1, fp) == 1) {
    printf("%s %d %d\n", buffer.name, buffer.age, buffer.id);
}
```

`fread` returns the number of items successfully read.  Here you request to read `1` item of size `sizeof(reg)`, if the item was read successfully, `fread` will return `1`, otherwise it will return `0` (in case of a read error or end of file reached).

Your screenshot shows a syntax error, which you seem to have fixed now.  Remove that, it is not helping.

In your function `register_new`, you are writing an uninitialized structure `reg` to the file, no wonder it does not contain anything useful when you read it back from the file. And for what it is worth, opening this file in binary mode is the correct thing to do since it contains binary data, namely the `int` members of the structure.

The `reg` passed to `fwrite` is indeed uninitialized.  `write_register` gets a copy of this uninitialized structure by value, and probably modifies this copy, but this does not affect the local structure in `register_new`. You should modify `write_register()` to take a pointer to the structure. Unlike C++, there is no passing by reference in C.

Comment: I get the why of the change, but why `== 1`? Does it return 0 when there is nothing more to read?

Comment: It is initialized, it is what the `write_register ( )` does.